# comparing elements of tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to make a code that compares the second element of each tuple and extract the tuples that contain duplicates of the second element.

For example, if I have

```
List = [(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)]

duplicate_tuples = [(0, 2), (3, 2)]  # desired output
```

I just cannot figure out how to designate the second element in my for iteration

```
for i in List: # would iterate each tuple
    if i[1] of i in List is duplicate...
```

Lack of pythonic grammar is frustrating. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Lack of pythonic grammar is fixed by reading tutorials.

Comment: What happens if more duplicates occur? Like if the list is `[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 0)]`? Then duplicates would be `[(0, 2), (3, 2)]` and `[(1, 0), (2, 0)]`. I'm assuming you want to report all duplicates.

Comment: @RoadRunner Indeed. My goal is to report all the duplicates.

Comment: @Julien I have it open, but I have hard time utilizing index position in loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance for more duplicates, So `groupby` is a better option.

```
In [6]: from itertools import groupby
In [7]: for g,l in groupby(sorted(lst,key=lambda x:x[1]),key=lambda x:x[1]):
   ...:     temp = list(l)
   ...:     if len(temp) > 1:
   ...:         print g,temp
   ...:   
2 [(0, 2), (3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can collect your tuples in a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), then report the lists that have more than one duplicate:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 0)]

dups = defaultdict(list)
for fst, snd in lst:
   dups[snd].append((fst, snd))

print([v for k, v in dups.items() if len(v) > 1])
# [[(0, 2), (3, 2)], [(1, 0), (2, 0)]]
```

Or keep the duplicates in a dictionary for easy lookups:

```
print({k: v for k, v in dups.items() if len(v) > 1})
# {2: [(0, 2), (3, 2)], 0: [(1, 0), (2, 0)]}
```

Comment: Don't use the keywords for variable names 'List'

Comment: @AILearning `List` is not a reserved keyword in Python. [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is. Although its probably better to call is something like `lst` instead.

Comment: True. Some other name would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Working in numpy arrays would be efficient instead of list/tuples.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2),(3,0)])

unique_vals,inverse_indices,counts=np.unique(a[:,1],return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
```

Based on the [unique function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) output, we can generate the duplicates list

```
duplicates=[(i,a[inverse_indices==i]) for i  in unique_vals[np.where(counts>1)[0]]]
```

Output:

```
[(0, array([[1, 0],[3, 0]])),
 (2, array([[0, 2],[3, 2]]))]
```

Comment: @V Anon, if your problem is resolved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using numpy:

```
duplicate_list = []

foo = np.array([(0,2), (1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (3,0), (1,2)])

for i in range(len(np.unique(foo[:,1]))):
    if np.sum(foo[:,1] == i) > 1:
        duplicate_list.append(foo[foo[:,1] == i].tolist())

print(duplicate_list)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 0], [3, 0]], [[0, 2], [3, 2], [1, 2]]]
```

With np.unique(foo[:,1]) we get the unique elements of the second element in a tuple, and then we append it to a list if the count is greater than 1 or duplicate is present, which returns 2 lists as we have 2 occurrences (0 and 2).
If you have a specific number say (2) then we can avoid the loop.

E.g.

```
bla = np.array([(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)])
duplicate = []

if np.sum(bla[:,1] == 2) > 1:
    duplicate = bla[bla[:,1] == 2].tolist()

print(duplicate)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2], [3, 2]]
```